# WP Rest API featured image on ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, rest, api

How can I show featured image in reactJS? I'm using Rest API with ReactJS. I had fetch every content. In the console, I can watch the `featured_media` value. How can I retrieve it in my reactJS image component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the featured image.

```
_embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url
```

here is an example:

```
this.state.posts.map(post=>
 <img
  alt="example"
  src={post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url}
  />
)
```

you will get more idea from here : https://github.com/BRdhanani/headless-wordpress-with-react